# Android: Send 0 byte to tcp socket to detect if the socket is still connected

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

So, I've read in many questions at stackoverflow that it is not possible to detect tcp socket disconnection without performing read/write on socket.

In .NET, it is possible to send 0 byte to the socket and check if the socket is still connected.

```
public bool isConnected()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
    SocketError socketError = SocketError.SocketError;
    socket.Send(buffer, 0, 0, SocketFlags.None, out socketError);
    return ((socketError == SocketError.Success) || (socketError == SocketError.WouldBlock));   //if it will block then the socket is alive!
}
```

It seems that it is not possible to send 0 byte in android/java because `OutputStream.write()` will not perform 0 byte write operation. Here is the code I get from definition:

```
public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if (b == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else if ((off < 0) || (off > b.length) || (len < 0) ||
               ((off + len) > b.length) || ((off + len) < 0)) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else if (len == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
        write(b[off + i]);
    }
}
```

Or did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: .NET simply passes the buffer down to the WinSock `send()` function, which allows a 0-length buffer as input: "***Calling send with a `len` parameter of zero is permissible** and will be treated by implementations as successful. In such cases, `send` will return zero as a valid value. For message-oriented sockets, a zero-length transport datagram is sent.*" As you already noticed, `OutputStream` validates the buffer length and will not pass a 0-length buffer down to the socket layer. Nothing you can do about that at this layer of coding. You would have to go down to the socket layer yourself.

Comment: To detect a closed socket, you have to send a real buffer, or read a real buffer, and then check for a real error. But that can only tell you if the connection has been close *gracefully*. A connection lost *abnormally* can't be detected in a timely manner, as it takes the OS a long time to internally timeout and invalidate the socket before reporting errors. Writing to a dead socket can succeed for awhile since data is buffered, so trying to implement `isConnected()` isn't very useful. That is just the nature of how sockets work. You should use timeouts in your protocol to detect dead sockets

Comment: In any case you should never try to predict the future. Even if you managed to write a valid `isConnected()` method, which you can't, for the reasons stated by @RemyLebeau, the connection state can change between then and the actual usage, so yo've accomplished exactly nothing. The correct way to test whether *any* resource is available is just to try to use it in the normal way, and cope with the errors *afterwards*.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for responding. I need this instead of using *"heartbeat"* to detect whether a connection to the server has been *lost/disconnected*. If it is not possible, I'll send a heartbeat byte to the server :)  @Remy, just out of curiosity, do you know how to go to *socket layer* in java? I would like to explore this option before go to my boss and tell him that I need to modify the server (the server has been running fine for more than 3 years serving Windows app before I am tasked to support Android. I don't want to fiddle around with the server code if possible).

Comment: "I need this instead of using *"heartbeat"* to detect whether a connection to the server has been *lost/disconnected*" - implementing `isConnected()` will not be able to do that reliably, so don't even try, it is not worth the effort. You don't necessarily need heartbeats, you can just use timeouts and handle any errors as they occur. Or, at the very least, you should turn on TCP keepalives.

Comment: Hi Remy, Thanks again for replying. The problem is that the client will wait for *"any update"* from the server with the timeout of 10 minutes. In .NET, if the connection aborted (eg. server crashed, etc), it will detect the failure immediately (and re-connect and if it failed, it switches to backup server automatically). But this is not the case in java. Java is unable to detect disconnection immediately. I am now googling on how to go to *socket layer* in java, but to no avail :(

Comment: NB 1. This *is* the sockets layer in Java. 2. The code you posted from `OutputStream.write()` is irrelevant. The output stream from a socket overrides that method.